# Remove square brackets between JSON file dumps

Tags: python, arrays, json

totally out of my depth here re Python and JSON so here goes for a dumbass question: I've written a script to download data from an API and write to file. It's a lot of data and the endpoint uses pagination, so I'm having to loop through it (1000 records at a time).

At the start and end of each 1000 records however I get open/close square brackets when actually the data just needs to be one large array.

I'm assuming there's a simple tweak to fix this? Potentially problem is my lack of grasp of Python data types...?

Here's the offending bit of code:

```
with open('filepath', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    while response.text != '[]':    
        json.dump(response.json(), f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        page += 1000
        response = requests.get(baseurl + f"&skip={page}", headers=headers)
```

How do I get rid of these square brackets between each 1000 records please?

[image]

Comment: Consider changing the file format from JSON to JSONL -- then each record goes to a separate line. Because you're dumping individual records, not lists of records, the problems you're running into here don't come up.

Comment: If your full dataset will fit in memory, you could also just retrieve the whole list in-memory before starting to write any of it to disk at all.

Comment: BTW, no reason to duplicate your tags in your title. Everyone seeing this question already knows it's about Python without that needing to be in the title. See [Should the coding language be in the title?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340972) and [Removing words from titles because they're in the tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251859) on [meta]. If it flows with the language it's welcome; if it's listing just tags for searchability, the site handles that on its own.

Comment: Way too big for memory - hence why writing to file. I will try JSONL though, thanks.

Comment: And @CharlesDuffy thanks for SO tips... I wasn't sure so erred on side of caution :D

Comment: np. Just be sure in using JSONL that you're telling it to write the objects inside the response instead of the response JSON itself (if it writes the full response you'll have one line per 1000-item batch, whereas if it writes the contents, each batch will append 1000 lines to the output file). If you use the jsonlines library, `write_all()` will do that; see https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Not that you _need_ to use a separate library to write a JSONL document; using the built-in JSON module can do it with some care.